# Will existing castles change to cities when I reform my government?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

So, I'm playing as tribal Scandinavia and am nearing the point where I'll have to decide whether I want to reform to become a republic or a feudal state. I have already reformed the Germanic faith and am finishing up the last buildings in my tribal holdings. I'd like to form into a republic, since there are no formidable opponents (I am constantly beating France in Holy Wars).

However, I currently possess five "normal" castle holdings, of which four have cities as baronies. Will the castle holdings turn into city holdings, if I choose to reform into a republic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how the Crusader Kings II Wiki describes the [process of becoming a republic](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Tribalism#Founding_a_merchant_republic):

> The decision to found a merchant republic requires a Large Market City and
>   the technology Trade Practices 1. Building the Large Market City requires
>   ? Town Infrastructure 1. For players, it has the additional requirements of a
>   coastal capital and The Republic DLC, in order to ensure the resulting realm
>   is playable.
>
> In addition to upgrading your capital to a city, it creates a duchy-level title
>   (if needed) and creates family palaces for you and four vassals of different
>   dynasties.
>
> Being a republic unlocks the convert to city decision for both you and
>   your direct vassals.

I assume by "upgrading your capital to a city" it means upgrading a tribal holding to a city holding. If your capital is a castle holding then I doubt the game would allow you to become a republic. It would probably break the game if it did. No other holdings would be upgraded automatically, but you should now be able to use the "Upgrade Tribal Settlements to City" decision to do so.

So your castles should remain as-is in your demesne, except as a Patrician you should longer have the -75% wrong holding type penalty.

Comment: The game prevents one from changing their capital to a non-tribe province until the government has been reformed. However, where this question comes from is if you give a "castle province" which has a city to a patrician vassal, the province capital becomes a city. I'll come by later to accept your answer after seeing how this folds out.

Comment: The capital of a province only changes when a character owns the capital of a province that doesn't match his own type and another holding in the same province that does match his type. In that case the other holding becomes the capital and the type of the province changes to match the new capital (and the character). The type of the two holdings doesn't change. If you give a county with a castle for a capital to a patrician that doesn't have any holdings in the county nothing changes. If the patrician owns a city in the county then the city becomes the capital and the castle becomes a barony.

Comment: Note that this means the type of one or more of your provinces could change when you become a republic. The capital of a province could change from a castle to a city in the same province if you have both in your demesne. However a castle holding will never change into a city holding as you asked in your question.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. So basically, I can revoke the cities from my vassals and that'll cause the province capitals to become cities. And I was using "change" in the sense of "changing clothes".